# Data Validation from Range OR any number in Google Sheets

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I'm creating data validation in Google Sheets that I would like to be able to accept either:

1. a selection from a range of cells or
2. any dollar amount from $0.01-$100.00.

I can see how to do either of these separately in separate cells using the "List from Range" or "Number" options but I don't see how to do **both** in the same cell.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  Do you really man any number? like from negative infinity to infinity?  otherwise, it might be possible to just "append" the list of possible numbers to the end of the range in question using a simple SEQUENCE() formula

Comment: Good point, the number is a dollar amount from 0-100, I edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: Adding 10k cells to accommodate the SEQUENCE() function would work, though it seems like a bit of a kluge. I was hoping for something that would stay within a function. Thanks for the idea, I may use it if necessary.

Comment: Have you considered doing this in Apps Script?

Comment: @Verbivore Does the answer provided do what you were looking for?

Comment: @Jescanellas I don't know how to code Apps Script. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a data validation formula that combines those two sets of criteria.

```
=or(and(D1>0,D1<=100),iferror(Match(D1,A2:A5,0)>0),0)
```

Enter the desired extra values, eg. 250, 999, in cells A2:A5.  Then apply the data correction formula to a cell, such as D1.

Here is a samle sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16cC7YKYLiG76Rn4tFSIraD1RILwsT0GQyymPat1WM-g/edit?usp=sharing

Let me know if this doesn't achieve the result you want, and I'll try again!

Comment: Hey Kirk, this works great! ...and it doesn't create a drop-down list. I'm guessing that there is not a way to put a formula into a list, and that it wouldn't work to have a range of numbers that large in a list anyway. I'm going with your solution. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the drop down list needs to be a reasonable length of values.  For $0.01 to $100 is 10,000 values, so not possible as a drop down. You could consider doing the data validation only for the other amounts, with a drop down list, and allow the user to also type in a value from $.01 to $100, then use conditional formatting to flaghighlight the cell if it didn't meet either the data vailidation, or 0 to $100.  If that is possible for your purpose.

Comment: @Verbivore  Glad I've helped.  I put an example of what I meant above in cell D7 in the sheet.  But that might not be good if you can't run any risk of a wrong amount being entered.